# Oracle: How to filter results based on a large number of IDs[20K]

Tags: database, oracle

I get a file as input, and I have to load data[In memory] corresponding to all the IDs present in the file.

I have tried following.

- Insert IDs into a temporary table and then do a join, but that is
  creating issues for parallel runs. Means multiple instances of same
  application cannot share same temp table. Here I cannot create one
  temp table per execution.
- 'in` clause where I can pass list of IDs, but there is a limit on
  size of query.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Can yuo use the file as if it was a table? e.g. http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_ext_tabs_spreadsheet.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [global temporary table](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_global_temporary_table_example.htm). The table definition is shared but each session gets its own set of private data.

Comment: How do I combine the inserts to GTT, with my main query. because data will be lost once a statement is complete. I am talking from C++ point of view.

Comment: The data is just deleted when you commit the transaction, not for each statement (and there's alternative syntax so it's not deleted on commit if that's what you need).

Answer (score 1):

**You can load the data in batches.** The `IN clause` limit is 1k for Oracle, so you can safely load entries by batches of 500 IDs for example.

*The best solution depends obviously on your exact circumstances, but this would work well for most cases. It does not involve write operations (like inserts into temp table) so there is no extra strain put on the DB (transaction log), no need for cleanup jobs, you save on redo logs, etc.*

Answer (score 0):

Use a collection:

```
CREATE TYPE number_tt IS TABLE OF NUMBER(8,0);
/

VARIABLE ids REFCURSOR;
/

DECLARE
  t_ids number_tt := number_tt();
BEGIN
  -- Loop through file to get IDs
  FOR id IN 1 .. 20000 LOOP
    t_ids.EXTEND;
    t_ids(t_ids.COUNT) := id;
  END LOOP;

  -- Use MEMBER OF instead of IN
  OPEN :ids FOR
  SELECT LEVEL
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL MEMBER OF t_ids;
END;
/

PRINT ids;
```